# Is every automorphism of a topological group continuous with regard to its own topology?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Is every automorphism of a topological group continuous with regard to its own topology?

Note that its inner automorphism obviously is continuous.

If the conclusion hold, then it follows that the connected component of a topological group containing the unit is a characteristic subgroup.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Q}$ are isomorphic as vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$. It will be a nice exercise to use this observation to give a counterexample to your last statement.

Comment: This should be on math.stackexchange. The answer is No. For example, there are uncountably many automorphisms of the field $\mathbb{C}$ which are discontinuous.

Comment: The connected component is not characteristic, in general: consider the group $\mathbb R\times\mathbb Q$ with the first factor in its usual topology and the second one in its discrete one.

Answer (score 5):

If $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is a number field (finite extension), any automorphism of $K$ can be extended to an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$. This is the standard way of showing that $\mathbb{C}$ has infinitely many field automorphisms. For example, there's an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ which swaps $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$.

On the other hand, any *continuous* automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ must keep $\mathbb{R}$ pointwise fixed, so it must either be the identity or complex conjugation.

Therefore, the topological groups $(\mathbb{C},+,0)$ and $(\mathbb{C},\cdot,1)$ both have uncountably many discontinuous group automorphisms.

Comment: Just to add to this answer: There are some interesting and important classes of topological groups  G such that every automorphism is a composition of a continuous automorphism with a field automorphism. For instance, if $G$ is the group of complex points of a semisimple algebraic group, e.g. $G=GL(n, C)$, $n\ge 2$. Furthermore, if $G$ is the group of real points of a semisimple algebraic group then every automorphism of $G$ is continuous.

Comment: Actually it's more than just uncountably, it's $2^c$ many automorphisms.

Comment: @YCor I don't think "uncountably" implies "of the cardinality of the continuum". It just means "more than countably many".

Comment: I agree with your last sentence, but I didn't say anything contrary. I'm saying that the number of field automorphisms of the complex field is even more than continuum, it's the power of continuum, $2^c=2^{2^{\omega}}$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it depends whom you ask: Pontryagin in his Topological Groups treatise (Pontryagin, L. S., Brown, A., & Naidu, P. S. V. (2018). Topological groups. Routledge) and Bourbaki in his General Topology book (Bourbaki, N. (2013). General Topology: Chapters 1–4 (Vol. 18). Springer Science & Business Media) require any automorphism of a topological group to be a homeomorphism. On the other hand Hewitt and Ross (Hewitt, E., & Ross, K. A. (2012). Abstract Harmonic Analysis: Volume I Structure of Topological Groups Integration Theory Group Representations (Vol. 115). Springer Science & Business Media) distinguish between automorphisms and topological automorphisms of a topological group. The latter being a homeomorphism.